# Slate - creating a TypeScript Function to filter and return an object with max property value

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

take a look at **NEW RELATED QUESTION:**

I want to filter an object set to retrieve the largest number of a column.

i do not know how to solve it. i try with max etc. But i think it is a skill problem. Here is my code so far:

```
     @Function()
    public async largestNumber(): Promise<Long> {
        const objResult = Objects.search()
                .dataMain()
                .filter(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.range. )
                .gt(100)
                .take(1);
                
        return objResult.max();
    }
```

This function returns objects with NULL values for the `lngPlanningNumber` property, which I would like to filter out.

**UPDATE:**

> Property 'isNotNull' does not exist on type 'INumericPropertyFilter'.

for

```
.filter(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.isNotNull()) // filter out NULL values
```

> Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Promise<number | null>'.

for

```
.take(1);
```

**NEW RELATED QUESTION:**
my code

```
    @Function()
    @Edits(XYZ)
    public async fctLargestNumber(): Promise<XYZ[]> {
        const maxObject = Objects.search()
                .xYZ()
                // .groupBy(e => e.lngPlanningNumber.topValues())
                // .segmentBy(e => e.lngPlanningNumber.topValues())
                // .filter(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.byIRanges({ min: 100000, max: 999999 }))
                .orderBy(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.desc())
                .takeAsync(1)
                //.valueOf();         
        return maxObject;
```

no i recieve an output like this:

```
[
{"typeId":"my-collection","primaryKey":{"id_pk":"ee1b1ac1-008b-479b-a748-01e8702927c9"}}
]
```

The question is now, how can i receive my result.

- How i can pick out the primary key value?
- How i can search for the requested result (integer) of column "lngPlanningNumber" which belongs to this id?

The Promise makes me curious.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that for numeric properties you'll only find the filters `exactMatch` and `range`. Nulls should get automatically removed when using these filters.

You can always try to do a range that gets all your values:

```
const flight: ExampleDataFlight[] = Objects.search().exampleDataFlight()
            .filter(row => row.taxiOut.range().gte(-99999).lte(99999))
            .all();
```

Regarding the `take(1)` take property requires ordering to show up. Here is an example where I randomly used `airtime` to force the `orderBy`, if you only want to do `take(1)` you can land any property here.

```
const flight: ExampleDataFlight[] = Objects.search().exampleDataFlight()
            .filter(row => row.taxiOut.range().gte(-99999).lte(99999))
            .orderBy(row => row.airTime.asc())
            .take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by filtering the object set, order by descending the desired column and then `take(1) or takeAsync(1)` .

```
  @Function()
public async largestObject(): Promise<DataMain[]> {
    return Objects.search()
            .dataMain()
            .filter(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.isNotNull())
            ..orderBy(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.desc())
            . takeAsync(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Function()
public async largestNumber(): Promise<DataMain[]> {
    const maxObject = Objects.search()
            .dataMain()
            .orderBy(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.desc())
            .takeAsync(1);         
    return maxObject;
}
```